# System.exit(1) from Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to intimate the caller if the spring batch is successful or not through the exit status.

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Foo.class);
app.setWebEnvironment(false);
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx= app.run(args);
SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(SimpleJobLauncher.class);
Job job = ctx.getBean("Foo", Job.class);
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();
try {
      //test
      JobExecution jobExec = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
      if(ExitStatus.FAILED.equals(jobExec.getExitStatus())){
            System.exit(1);
}catch(JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            logger.error("Exception in Foo"+e,e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

But the program is not returning the value back to the caller. I am invoking the program from Unix script and the Unix process is keep on running.

Comment: jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters); immediately gets back to the caller so the job is still running, you need to wait for the finished execution

Comment: Yeah I coded in a way to wait for the job to get completed. But the problem here is the System.exit(1); is not returning the controller to the caller. The process is keep on running in Unix.

Comment: did you debug it? the condition is not met (exitStatus=FAILED) so the System.exit(-1) will not work, you need at least an else branch which reacts on the other status conditions

Comment: I am exiting in case of an exception. I am writing the exit statement in the catch block.

Comment: it seems process doesn't throw exception and has not failed, which means job is running..you need see loggers , whether reader/processor/writer is running... or you can have a custom reader/processor/writer to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than this custom code to launch your job via Command Line, I would just launch your job via `CommandLineJobRunner`. It handles you `System.exit()` for you.

[GrepCode link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.java) if you want to see how they do it